# Stokes Theorem implementation

Tags: calculus

I would please like to ask for your guidance to the following excercise:

Let the surface $S:\{1\le x^2+y^2\le 4, z=3\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and 
$\vec F=\langle-y, x, xyz\rangle$
I would like to integrate the function $\vec\nabla\times\vec F$ through Stokes Theorem. I have found the curve which we need so that to use in in order to calculate the integral for this curve, but I have found difficulty in expressing this curve in a parametrical way.

I would appreciate for your quidance. 
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Along the surface $S$, $\vec r=\langle x,y,z\rangle=\langle r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,3\rangle$, so the differential is
$$d\vec r=\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0\rangle\,dr+\langle-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0\rangle\,d\theta$$
Thus the areal element is
$$d^2\vec A=\pm\langle\cos\theta,\sin\theta,0\rangle\,dr\times\langle-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,0\rangle\,d\theta=\pm\langle0,0,r\rangle\,dr\,d\theta$$
We have to decide which way we consider to be up on the surface and we arbitrarily choose the $+z$ direction, so $d^2\vec A=\langle0,0,r\rangle\,dr\,d\theta$. Then
$$\vec F=\langle-y,x,xyz\rangle=\langle-r\sin\theta,r\cos\theta,3r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\rangle$$
And then
$$\vec\nabla\times\vec F=\langle xz-0,0-yz,1-(-1)\rangle=\langle3r\cos\theta,-3r\sin\theta,2\rangle$$
So we get
$$\begin{align}\int\int_S\vec\nabla\times\vec F\cdot d^2\vec A&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^2\langle3r\cos\theta,-3r\sin\theta,2\rangle\cdot\langle0,0,r\rangle\,dr\,d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^22r\,dr\,d\theta=6\pi\end{align}$$
As we walk forward around the boundary of the surface with our head up, the surface lies to our left, so when traversing $C_1$ on the outer boundary where $r=2$ of the surface we walk counterclockwise in the direction of increasing $\theta$ while as we walk around the inner boundary $C_2$ where $r=1$, we must walk clockwise in the direction of decreasing $\theta$. Thus
$$\begin{align}\oint\vec F\cdot d\vec r=&\int_{C_1}\vec F\cdot d\vec r+\int_{C_2}\vec F\cdot d\vec r\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\langle-2\sin\theta,2\cos\theta,12\sin\theta\cos\theta\rangle\cdot\langle-2\sin\theta,2\cos\theta,0\rangle\,d\theta\\
&+\int_0^{-2\pi}\langle-\sin\theta,\cos\theta,3\sin\theta\cos\theta\rangle\cdot\langle-\sin\theta,\cos\theta,0\rangle\,d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}4\,d\theta-\int_{-2\pi}^0d\theta=8\pi-2\pi=6\pi\end{align}$$
To find $d\vec r$ along the boundary we simply used the fixed value of $r$ at each bounding curve and noted that $dr=0$ as we went around the boundary in our general expression for $d\vec r$ above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your analytical approach.